# Venn diagrams with tikz: erase arc

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE, which produces the  Venn diagram below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pstricks,pst-jtree}
% pst-jtree enables the \multiline \cr \endmultiline syntax
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{center}
  \def\first{(0,0) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \def\second{(2.7,0) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \def\third{(1.45,1.5) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \first node [below] { };
    \draw \second node [below] { };
    \draw \third node [above] { };

    % first coordinate control x axis, second controls y axis
    \node at (-1.1,-.3) (A) {first};
    \node at (3.8,-.5) (B) {second};
    \node at (2.1,.8) (C) {\multiline we care\cr about this\endmultiline};
    \node at (1.5,2.5) (C) {third};

    \begin{scope}[fill opacity = .5]
      \clip \third;
      \fill[light-gray] \second;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For aesthetic reasons, I don't want the line of the `first` ellipse to interfere with the `we care about this` legend. Is it possible to eliminate the arc of `first` in the shaded area?

Comment: `\fill` first with a white color with no opacity, and then the `light-gray` with opacity as you wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the drawing order:

1. First ellipse
2. Gray area
3. Second and third ellipses and text nodes.

Further remarks:

- Multi-line text is enabled by node option `align`.
- `light-gray` is a little an unhappy color name because of the hyphen. When the shorthand notation `\fill[light-gray]` is used, TikZ misinterprets the hyphen as arrow  specification, when the color is undefined (as in the example of the question). TikZ complains about an unknown arrow tip `light` instead of an undefined color error as for `fill=light-gray` or an unknown key.

Example file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \def\first{(0,0) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \def\second{(2.7,0) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \def\third{(1.45,1.5) ellipse (6em and 4em)}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \first node [below] { };
    \begin{scope}
      \clip \third;
      \fill[lightgray] \second;
    \end{scope}
    \draw \second node [below] { };
    \draw \third node [above] { };

    % first coordinate control x axis, second controls y axis
    \node at (-1.1,-.3) (A) {first};
    \node at (3.8,-.5) (B) {second};
    \node[align=center] at (2.1,.8) (C) {we care\\ about this};
    \node at (1.5,2.5) (C) {third};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]